# Angular Material 5 - Show full text in Mat Lists ( Word Wrap )

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am creating a chat box each message is a angular material mat list. https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview.

However, if the message is really long instead of increasing the height and going onto next line, it cuts the message and displays an ellipse. As shown in the image below.

[image]

```
 <mat-list dense>     
    <mat-list-item class="chat-message-body" *ngIf="auth._id !== message.author._id" fxLayoutAlign="" dir="ltl">
        <div matLine>
            <b>{{message.author.profile.username}} </b>
            <span>{{message.created_at | date:'shortTime'}} </span>
        </div>
        <span matLine> {{message.body}} </span>
        <img matListAvatar class="img-box" src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x30" alt="...">
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

How do i force it to show the full text

Comment: use a card instead if you want to show large text elements

Comment: Card will add a shadow border etc around it, seems like more work to remove things to me. Whats wrong with using a list? Lists seems more appropriate for chat box instead of a card

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use the following css:

```
::ng-deep .mat-list .mat-list-item .mat-line{
     word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

or

```
::ng-deep .mat-line{
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
  white-space: pre-wrap !important;
}
```

Height of mat-list-item is limited to 48px so we need to override in case of large text

```
::ng-deep  .mat-list .mat-list-item{
  height:initial!important;
}
```

Demo:https://plnkr.co/edit/tTlhYgTkSz1QcgqjCfqh?p=preview

[Link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) to know more about the word-wrap and white-spac

Comment: On which element?

Comment: <div matLine style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">

Comment: tried overriding of existing css class but not working so direct setting the style attribute

Comment: @KHAN updated the answer, override the .mat-line class

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/R1SyWGoDClRefsW59XKn?p=preview it dies not work well

Comment: @KHAN This happens due to limited height available for mat-list-item.I fixed my demo template too, have a look

::ng-deep  .mat-list .mat-list-item{
  height:initial!important;
}

Comment: @mohituprim after posting that plunker yesterday i decided to switch to use angular flex-layout to layout my chat. Its much simpler with more control

Comment: But i guess this sovles the problem of the question so i have marked it as a solution

Comment: Avoid using `::ng-deep` (global styles and in this case from a component. It's deprecated btw.). In this case it's not needed. Try `.mat-line { word-wrap: break-word; white-space: unset; }`. Also `!important` is not necessary. Another thing what should be avoided.

Answer (score 6):

***Simply wrap your whole paragraph inside of `<mat-list-item>` with `<p>` tags*** and that will force correct styles. Makes sense... No need for styles in this case.

```
<mat-list-item>
  <p>
    My super long text..........
  </p>
</mat-list-item>
```

Answer (score 5):

I created this css/scss class.

```
    /* CSS */
    .mat-list-item.mat-list-item-word-wrap {
      height: initial !important;
    }
    .mat-list-item-word-wrap .mat-line {
      word-wrap: break-word !important; 
      white-space: pre-wrap !important;
    }
```

or

```
    /* SCSS */
    .mat-list-item.mat-list-item-word-wrap {
      height: initial !important;
      .mat-line {
        word-wrap: break-word !important; 
        white-space: pre-wrap !important;
      }
    }
```

html:

```
    <mat-list>
      <mat-list-item class="mat-list-item-word-wrap">
        <mat-icon mat-list-icon>description</mat-icon>
        <h3 mat-line>{{ description }}</h3>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
```

see example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6mhz2x

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone reading this post was looking to wrap the dense mat list `<mat-list dense>`, add `[dense]` to [mohit uprim's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8297020/mohit-uprim) answer above:

```css
::ng-deep .mat-list[dense] .mat-list-item .mat-line {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

HI have you tried with the CSS property `word-break` or `overflow-break` ?