# Handling card overflow text

Tags: html, css, angular-material, overflow, styling

I have this card container to display some text that is overflowing

[image]

I need the text to be wrapped inside the card container and the container to adjust it height to show all wrapped text.

I already tried to use options like `overflow-wrap`, `word-wrap`, `white-space` without success, the text will not break and fill the below white space.

The card is a `mat-card` from the Angular Material library.

EDIT: html code of the component

```
<mat-card>

    <mat-card-content>
        <mat-list>
            <mat-list-item>
                <mat-icon matListIcon>tag</mat-icon>
                <p matLine> <b> ID </b> </p>
                <p matLine>
                    <span matLine> id </span>
                </p>
            </mat-list-item>

            <mat-list-item>
                <mat-icon matListIcon>edit_attributes</mat-icon>
                <p matLine> <b>TYPE</b> </p>
                <p matLine>
                    <span> type </span>
                </p>
            </mat-list-item>

            <mat-list-item>
                <mat-icon matListIcon>games</mat-icon>
                <p matLine> <b>CONTROLLER</b> </p>
                <p matLine>
                    <span> controller </span>
                </p>
            </mat-list-item>

            <mat-list-item>
                <mat-icon matListIcon>vpn_key</mat-icon>
                <p matLine> <b>PUBLIC KEY</b> </p>
                <p matLine>
                    <span> 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 </span>
                </p>

            </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>

    </mat-card-content>

</mat-card>
```

EDIT2:

Using

```
span {
  word-break: break-all;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

will not help as it won't break the long text line

[image]

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47379645/9780816) will break the spacings

[image]

Comment: Share your code, what you have done so far?

Comment: @RakeshK check edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`word-break: break-all` will handle that:

```css
span {
  word-break: break-all;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<span> 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 </span>
```

Added `display: inline-block`:

```css
span {
  word-break: break-all;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span> 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 </span>
```

Comment: It won't work, even after removing `overflow: hidden` from the wrapper div

Comment: There must be framework css that is more specific (I mean the selector) than the simple css I provided. Try to improve the specificity. You could try `!important` to see if it helps. If it does help then you should improve the specificity and get rid of `!important`.

Comment: I tried to apply the `word-break: break-all` rule traversing all the DOM elements all the wey down the innermost one, but it doesn't break the text

Comment: @AntonioSantoro do you have other things than what you provided that are interfering with this? Rob's solution works for me when I simply add that to the ```span``` element.

Comment: I edited the answer to match your use of `<span>` and you can see in the snippet it still works BUT the border acts differently. Try to add `display: inline-block` to fix that behavior.

Comment: @AntonioSantoro The more I google, the more I see that this is a fairly common issue for mat-lists in Angular. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377146/angular-material-5-show-full-text-in-mat-lists-word-wrap) might help.

Comment: @RobMoll please check my edits because the solution doesn't work

Comment: @AntonioSantoro The edits look fine. Did you check out the link I posted in my last comment? There are some issues with mat-list and text wrapping but the link seemed to help others.

Comment: Yes, I tried the solutions suggested in there, the second image shows the result that breaks spacings

Comment: @RobMoll https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6mhz2x-jnhb6t?file=app/list-sections-example.html it works but not for me

Comment: @AntonioSantoro Okay. Sounds like you're making progress. Now try wrapping that in a card like you have to see if that breaks it.

Comment: I might solved by removing some white space that were inside the `span` that contains the long text, as long as I remove any leftover white space it works as that example, why is that happening?

Comment: @AntonioSantoro I'm not sure. I left those blank spaces in my snippet just in case they were causing issues but did not affect the result in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing following:

Give a class to span which holding the text. Suppose you gave class named `.token` then in css do this.

```
::ng-deep .token {
      word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: not working, are you sure the syntax is correct?

Comment: Are you using `css` or `scss` ?

Comment: I'm using css````